# Is ワンサイズ a valid Japanese word?

Tags: meaning, words, loanwords

Japanese For Busy People volume II, revised third edition, on page 23 has

> To state or ask how much bigger, you use other words.
>   ワンサイズ大きいのはありませんか。
>   Do you have one that is a size bigger?

However, the word (as of today) doesn't exist on forvo.com, on jisho.org (either as a word or in its corpora), the English or Japanese editions of Wiktionary, and on weblio it's only mentioned in sentences.

Is ワンサイズ a valid Japanese word, in that it's easily understood, unambiguous, and the most common way of expressing the concept of a difference of one size?

The only explanation I can think of as to why it's valid but not in dictionaries is that it's merely regarded as a combination of the words "ワン" and "サイズ".

Comment: @downvoter - what more research should I have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly valid as a Japanese expression and is understood by virtually everyone (except for very old people). [ALC has several examples of ワンサイズ](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA). Although uncommon, you can say ツーサイズ, too. A non-katakana equivalent would be 一段階.

Comment: As an aside, [スリーサイズ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA) usually refers to something totally different, "bust/waist/hip measurements." :)